Interval declared in useEffect not being cleared
An Interval is declared in a useEffect. This interval goes ahead and conditionally sets the src property on an iframe, referenced by useRef. The goal is to reload the iframe, if it hasn't been loaded yet.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getRemoteUrl } from "../utils/getRemoteUrl";
import { mapUrl } from "../utils/mapUrl";

interface Props {
  setUrl: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}

const PdfViewer = (props: Props) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);
  const { filename, encoded } = useParams();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (encoded && filename) {
      const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
      const mappedUrl = mapUrl(decodedUrl);
      props.setUrl(mappedUrl);

      const localUrl = `${mappedUrl}/${encodeURIComponent(filename)}`;
      const iframeUrl = `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${getRemoteUrl(
        localUrl
      )}&embedded=true`;

      const iframe = ref.current;
      if (iframe) {
        iframe.src = iframeUrl;
        if (intervalId.current) clearInterval(intervalId.current);
        intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
          if (!loaded) {
            iframe.src = iframeUrl;
          } else if (intervalId.current) {
            clearInterval(intervalId.current);
          }
        }, 5000);
      }

      return () => {
        if (intervalId.current) {
          clearInterval(intervalId.current);
        }
      };
    }
  }, [filename, encoded, props.setUrl, loaded]);

  if (!filename) {
    return <h1>No file found</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <p className="text-center">
        This might take a while. Try refreshing the page periodically.
        <br></br>If the file is not loading, try{" "}
        <a
          className="underline"
          href={getRemoteUrl(
            mapUrl(decodeURIComponent(encoded!)) +
              `/${encodeURIComponent(filename)}`
          )}
        >
          downloading it.
        </a>
      </p>
      <iframe
        ref={ref}
        className="w-full h-[80vh]"
        title="pdf"
        onLoad={() => {
          setLoaded(true);
        }}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfViewer;


Expected: When the iframe loads, "loaded" becomes true and thus no further request to docs.google.com will be made.
Reality: No matter what, every 5 seconds a request is made to docs.google.com sometimes returning as a 200 and refreshing the iframe, making the app unusable.

Don't use if (!loaded) { in the interval callback. It's a constant, and won't change while the effect runs. Changing the state will re-run the effect anyway since it has loaded in its dependency list.

You don't need a ref for intervalId (and the type of nodeJS.Timer is certainly wrong). Just declare a local variable in your effect callback. You stop the interval when the effect is cleared anyway.

I made a sample app to test this, but wasn't unable to consistently reproduce the behavior. There were times where the loaded state was set to true and I still had intervals running, but I'm not sure if that was a quirk of codesandbox's hot-reload or if it was the issue you're describing.
Here is a link to my sandbox if this is useful for debugging: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jolly-chaplygin-mgfwdt
My immediate thoughts are to check if you have interval tasks which were opened and never disposed of. Debugging this can be done by console logging the interval's reference ID. I have a hunch this might be the case. If your iframe is being refreshed every 5 seconds, there must a rogue interval somewhere.
Another option could be to remove if (!loaded) from within the setInterval callback, and instead move its negation to the top of your useEffect to short circuit once loaded is true. This would prevent you from queueing a new setInterval task, only to immediately dispose of it.
useEffect(() => {
   if (loaded) {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current)
      // return here if necessary
   };

   // additional logic
}, [filename, encoded, props.setUrl, loaded])

